# Is it legal to sell a product that has been stolen?

Tags: business

Someone can somehow buy lots of products and sell them for very low prices.

Can I buy from him at low price and sell it for normal price?

I'm not from US, but products may be.

Comment: Note that USA law wouldn't normally apply unless a crime occurred in US territory, either the theft or the sale.

Comment: If you're not in the US, you should update the country tag.

Comment: you should probably update the country tag anyway, the US isn't the centre of the world

Answer (score 3):

Assuming USA law:

https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/2315

If you accept or buy goods that are knowingly stolen you may be fined or imprisoned.

If you buy goods and later find out they were stolen you can sue for a refund.  However, I'd say the likelihood of getting your money back is incredibly low.

Comment: A while ago I read up about "attempted crimes" and found surprisingly that buying things that you _believe_ are stolen but are not actually stolen is an "attempt to buy stolen goods" and a crime in the USA. Obviously the buyer will be the legal owner if the goods were never stolen.

Comment: @gnasher729: I'm pretty sure that law is there so the FBI can perform undercover operations.

Answer (score 0):

@NotMe has dealt with the criminal aspects, the civil aspects are that at common law you do not have good title to a piece of stolen property. That is, legally it belongs to the person from whom it was taken and they can turn up at any time and demand its return from the person who currently possesses it.

Negotiable instruments like cash, stocks, bonds and cheques are an exception to this, a person who, in good faith, accepts one of these has good title even if they have been previously stolen.